# redirect page on my error page

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i create a site where i use the custom error in my web.config. But problem is that when user type abcd.aspx then error page is displaying . When user type abcd only its display 400.0 error of server how can i manage this . When user type anything that is not in project, its open 400.aspx of my project . 
Below is my web.config

```
 <system.web>
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx?type=error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx?type=404"/>
</customErrors>
```

Please advice me how can i do that .

Answer (score 0):

Your custom error setting is fine and that should work.

Is 404.aspx page in MasterPage?

**Make sure this page not requre any session to be accessed.**

Just for testing add **error.htm** and test whether you can't access this page too.

**Update**

check this setting as well in web.config: `<deployment retail="true" />`. This should be false.

Comment: for your comment yes this page is under masterpage but i am not using anytype of session on my masterpage file

Comment: this work on local but when i deployee this on the server this not work . I type in url  www.mysitename.com\abcd -- not work www.mysitename.com\abcd.aspx this works

Comment: have you tested with error.htm page? even see my edit.

Comment: when i use the <deployment retails="false" /> the url is not finding any other page when i run the application

Comment: I create a html page as you say but still this work on local but not work when i deploy on server